# How to merge rows and convert them into columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID  START   END  SEQ
1   11      12   1
1   14      15   3 
1   13      14   2
2   10      14   1
3   11      15   1
3   16      17   2
```

I need to transform it into this DataFrame:

```
ID  START_1  END_1  SEQ_1  START_2  END_2  SEQ_2 START_3  END_3  SEQ_3
1   11       12     1      13       14     2     14       15     3 
2   10       14     1      NA       NA     NA    NA       NA     NA   
3   11       15     1      16       17     2     NA       NA     NA
```

The problem is that the number of rows with the same ID is unknown apriori, which means that the maximum number of columns `START_X`, `END_X`, `SEQ_X` should not be defined manually.
Is there any automated way to do this transformation, taking into account that columns should be ordered by `SEQ`?
Should I use `group_by` or which should be the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), then [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last remove `MultiIndex` from columns by `list comprehension`:

```
df['SEQ1'] = df.SEQ
df = df.groupby(['ID','SEQ1']).mean().unstack()
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df.columns]
print (df)
    START_1  END_1  SEQ_1  START_2  END_2  SEQ_2  START_3  END_3  SEQ_3
ID                                                                     
1      11.0   12.0    1.0     13.0   14.0    2.0     14.0   15.0    3.0
2      10.0   14.0    1.0      NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
3      11.0   15.0    1.0     16.0   17.0    2.0      NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), `aggfunc='mean'` is by default:

```
df['SEQ1'] = df.SEQ
df = df.pivot_table(index= ['ID','SEQ1']).unstack()
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df.columns]
print (df)
    END_1  SEQ_1  START_1  END_2  SEQ_2  START_2  END_3  SEQ_3  START_3
ID                                                                     
1    12.0    1.0     11.0   14.0    2.0     13.0   15.0    3.0     14.0
2    14.0    1.0     10.0    NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
3    15.0    1.0     11.0   17.0    2.0     16.0    NaN    NaN      NaN
```

Comment: One question, @jezrael. This code generates extra row just below the header and puts `ID` in this row, while other headers are in the first row. Is it possible to solve it? Actually I opened a new thread, just if you'd like to help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723561/transformation-of-dataframe)