# Transformation of pandas DataFrame adds a blank row

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

My original question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710303/how-to-merge-rows-and-convert-them-into-columns). I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID  START   END  SEQ
1   11      12   1
1   14      15   3 
1   13      14   2 
2   10      14   1
3   11      15   1
3   16      17   2
```

I wanted to transform it into this DataFrame:

```
ID  START_1  END_1  SEQ_1  START_2  END_2  SEQ_2 START_3  END_3  SEQ_3
1   11       12     1      13       14     2     14       15     3 
2   10       14     1      NA       NA     NA    NA       NA     NA   
3   11       15     1      16       17     2     NA       NA     NA
```

After `pivot_table` transformations I received a DataFrame that has an additional blank row after the header:

```
test_2['SEQ1'] = test_2.SEQ
test_2 = test_2.pivot_table(index= ['ID','SEQ1']).unstack()
test_2 = test_2.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
test_2.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in test_2]
test_2
```

test_2

```
    START_1  END_1  SEQ_1  START_2  END_2  SEQ_2 START_3  END_3  SEQ_3
ID
1   11       12     1      13       14     2     14       15     3 
2   10       14     1      NA       NA     NA    NA       NA     NA   
3   11       15     1      16       17     2     NA       NA     NA
```

How can I delete these row and align all the headers? I tried to delte the row in a conventional way using `test2[:2]`, but it didn't delete the blank row.

EDIT:

This is the more realistic dataset's extract:

```
ID  INDEX           START                   END                 SEQ     NUM_PREV     NUM_ACTUAL   NUM_NEXT             TIME   PRE_TIME      LOC_IND
079C    333334.0    2016-06-23 12:45:32 2016-06-23 12:51:05 1   1      23456           25456           29456           30      2               YES
079C    333334.0    2016-06-23 12:47:05 2016-06-23 12:51:05 2   2     29456           39458           39945           20      0               NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider resetting index after the pivot/unstack operation:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data='''
ID  START   END  SEQ
1   11      12   1
1   14      15   3 
1   13      14   2 
2   10      14   1
3   11      15   1
3   16      17   2
'''

test_2 = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep="\\s+")
seq = set(test_2['SEQ'].tolist())

test_2['SEQ1'] = test_2.SEQ
test_2 = test_2.pivot_table(index= ['ID','SEQ1']).unstack()
test_2 = test_2.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
test_2.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in test_2]

test_2 = test_2.reset_index()
#    ID  END_1  SEQ_1  START_1  END_2  SEQ_2  START_2  END_3  SEQ_3  START_3
# 0   1   12.0    1.0     11.0   14.0    2.0     13.0   15.0    3.0     14.0
# 1   2   14.0    1.0     10.0    NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
# 2   3   15.0    1.0     11.0   17.0    2.0     16.0    NaN    NaN      NaN
```

However, as you can see it changes column ordering, so consider a nested list comprehension with `sum()` to flatten it, all for a suitable order:

```
seqmax = max(seq)+1
colorder = ['ID'] +  sum([['START_'+str(i),'END_'+str(i),'SEQ_'+str(i)]
                     for i in range(1, seqmax) if i in seq],[])

test_2 = test_2[colorder]

#    ID  START_1  END_1  SEQ_1  START_2  END_2  SEQ_2  START_3  END_3  SEQ_3
# 0   1     11.0   12.0    1.0     13.0   14.0    2.0     14.0   15.0    3.0
# 1   2     10.0   14.0    1.0      NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
# 2   3     11.0   15.0    1.0     16.0   17.0    2.0      NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I get the error `KeyError not in index`. And there should be probably `idmax = max(test_2['SEQ'])+1`

Comment: Not quite sure where that error derives. I update my post showing how I reproduced your data and pivot code (using exactly as you posted). Maybe your actual data differs.

Comment: I just have more columns in my real dataset, e.g. `ID  START   END  SEQ TIME DATE ...`. The first methods, for some reason, does not include some of the columns in the new dataframe, and that's what I misunderstand. Why not all columns are included? And the second method probably does not assume that `ID` might be non-numeric like `11A`.

Comment: Got it. See update. Simply run `reset_index()` and be sure to capture a list of sequences. See `seq = set(test_2['SEQ'].tolist())` before pivot/unstack to use later for column ordering.

Comment: Sorry, but where `seq` is then used in the first solution?

Comment: Thanks. The first solution with `reset_index()` works except as I mentioned that some columns disappear... The second solution still gives the same error, but it doesn't matter since I would be more interested in `pivot_table` approach.

Comment: I wish I could see your data. Resetting index should not be dropping columns.

Comment: Sorry, for not publishing the real dataset's sample. Please see my edit to see the whole list of columns and some sample rows.

Comment: Forgive me but those dropped columns is not relevant in this question about headers, but more pertinent in your last question. The unstack/pivot method drops any non-numeric columns. In your last question, you should have showed full dataset then, too!

Comment: You are right. I will have to publish a new question or convert string columns to numeric ones. I didn't know this fact. Thanks for noticing.